# C#: Could I use the following method to permanently delete a file from the hard drive?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, io

I won't post code or anything as I have not yet started this project. But could I theoretically securely delete a file using this method:

Use `System.IO.File` to write all 0 bytes and replace the bytes currently in the file (or even randomize the bytes if desired).

Perhaps randomize the file attributes for added security

Then finally delete the file

Now, I understand that even with this method the file will still technically be stored in the memory even following deletion, but if I overwrite all bytes in the file and randomize the attributes, would the file still be recoverable?

Comment: That depends on whether the file system writes the overwrite on the same location on disk, I guess. No idea about that. Looks more like something to leave to some kind of hard disk scrubber tool.

Comment: I don't see how opening a file for overwriting could ever store its contents in memory, though. You kind of need to specifically read a file stream for that.

Comment: This article can help you : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22736/Securely-Delete-a-File-using-NET

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is what professional eraser-tools ([CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for example) also do. However I say "professional" as it is not that easy to permanently delete a file and those programs do this usually by performing your mentioned algorithm a given amount of times, usually up to 10.

However there´s always a chance to recover the files and national security agencies deal with this all day. So there is no 100% safe approach, but you can be sure it will get very hard after a few iterations to recover your files - and even *if* they might recover something it is not guaranteed to be whole file but just a bunch of unordered bytes.